# Rename auto-generated virtual key field

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, foreign-keys

SQL database, in mvc project I use EF to create model classes. One of the classes has two fields related to one field of another class, many-to-one relation. They are named like "Field" and "Field1" in this linked class. Is there a way to rename auto-generated names of these two virtual fields in the class?

**EDIT.** Or maybe just a conclusion.

It looks like it's a messy topic about linking a database to an asp.net application. There are different approaches and tools and there are ways to abstract from it like partial classes, viewmodels, automappers and all with their own bugs and workarounds... and there is no a comprehensive tutorial on all this stuff explaining what and when and how to use... such a visual development environment... pure easiness.

Comment: Change the names in the model class, update the applicationdbcontext class, add migration, and update database?

Comment: You shouldn't ever operate on EDMX manually. Either use the model designer to make the applicable changes or regenerate them from your database after modifying the database. However, at this point, you should be avoiding EDMX altogether. It's deprecated. Use Code First Despite the name, it can be used to create a new database or work with an existing one. In other words, it's a complete replacement for both Model First and Database First.

Comment: If you are not using code first approach, it is useless to change the names. You can make partial classes if you need additionnal code

Comment: Yes. There is nothing you can do with Model First/Database First that can't be done via Code First. View models really have nothing to do with anything. That's all about how you map data to/from the view model class, and would present the same issues despite the entity source. Your M2M relationships is all about configuration. If they didn't work, you didn't have something configured properly. It's hard to say what out of context, though.